# Which is Jest way for restoring mocked function

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jestjs

In Sinon's stub it is very easy to restore functionality.

```
const stub = sinon.stub(fs,"writeFile",()=>{})
...
fs.writeFile.restore()
```

I am looking to do the same thing with Jest. The closest I get is this ugly code:

```
const fsWriteFileHolder = fs.writeFile
fs.writeFile = jest.fn()
...
fs.writeFile = fsWriteFileHolder
```

Comment: Have you tried `mockRestore `, its not documented yet but it is part `spyOn` example in the docs.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Finally I found a workable solution thanks to @nbkhope's contribution.

So the following code work as expected, i.e. it mocks the code and then it restore the original behavior:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(
    fs,
    'writeFile' 
  ).mockImplementation((filePath,data) => {
  ...
})
...
spy.mockRestore()
```

Comment: Interesting! Is that (spyOn) a new function? I can't find it in the docs yet.

Comment: Oh nevermind! I just found it. And it's [available from v19.0.0+](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname). Cool!

Comment: @dejan Thanks for sharing the solution. However, your solution does not work for me since I am mocking up `console.log`. Any idea? See my code below

    **const spy = jest.spyOn(global.console, 'error').mockImplementation(err 
    => errors.push(err));
    spy.mockRestore();**

Comment: Thanks,  this explanation was better than the docs on jests website.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to [clear all the calls](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockclear) to the mock function, you can use:

```
const myMock = jest.fn();
// ...
myMock.mockClear();
```

To [clear everything](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockreset) stored in the mock, try instead:

```
myMock.mockReset();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't work. It seems I have to settle for my initial ugly solution.

Comment: @DejanToteff It seems like you are redefining the fs.writeFile function to be a jest.fn(). mockClear and mockReset are used for the jest mock function, not the function that was previously defined as fs.writeFile. Your solution seems reasonable. After redefinition, does the writeFile function not revert back to normal after the test is over? This post seems to be related, check it out: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Yes, my solution behaves just fine. My only trouble was that the code would look better if the Jest's restore functionality was possible in this case.

Comment: [`mockClear()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear) and [`mockReset()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreset) apparently don't restore the original function. [`mockRestore()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore) does, but can't be used with [`jest.fn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestfnimplementation): _"mockFn.mockRestore() only works when the mock was created with jest.spyOn(). Thus you have to take care of restoration yourself when manually assigning jest.fn()."_

Answer (score 0):

`jest.spyOn()` is helpful when mocking and unmocking methods, however there might be a situation where you want to mock and unmock esModule.

I had such situation recently and I found this solution to work for me:

```
// Module that will be mocked and unmocked
import exampleModule from 'modules/exampleModule';

const ActualExampleModule = jest.requireActual('modules/exampleModule');

describe('Some tests that require mocked module', () => {
  // Tests on mock
});

describe('Some tests that require original module', () => {
  it('Test with restored module', async () => {
    const restoredModule = await import('modules/exampleModule');
    restoredModule.default = ActualExampleModule .default;

    // Now we can assert on original module
  });
});
```